# Why aren't some flags accepted by rsync?

Tags: rsync

I tried to pass `rsync -rutz --no-l --no-L --no-k --no-K --no-H $HOME/testdir /run/media/USER/HDD/` but it failed, telling me `rsync: --no-L: unknown option`. So I tried replacing `--no-L` with `--no-copy-links`, which failed as well.

Two of the other flags didn't pass, either: `--no-k` and `--no-K`. Removing the mentioned flags worked, though.

What I am trying to do is to copy dirs and its contents without copying *any* of the links (symlinks, hard links etc.) and without preserving their attributes (ownership, group, perms etc.). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `man` page:

> --no-OPTION
> You may turn off one or more implied options by prefixing the option name with "no-".  Not all  options  may be  prefixed  with a "no-": only options that are implied by other options (e.g. --no-D, --no-perms) or have different defaults in various circumstances (e.g. --no-whole-file, --no-blocking-io,  --no-dirs).   You  may specify  either  the  short  or  the  long  option  name  after the "no-" prefix (e.g. --no-R is the same as --no-relative).

`-L` doesn't appear to be implied by any other option, nor does `-k` or `-K`.  If you don't want the functionality, don't add the option, there is no need to negate it.

I haven't investigated `--no-l` or `--no-H` since they seem to work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Martin. Yeah, I got the info from the `man` pages, too. Alright, so I can just assume that those three flags (`kKL`) aren't needed because they need to be specifically passed in the first place?

Comment: That's what the `man` page says.  `k` and `K` both have phrases "This options causes ... Without this option ..." so presence or absence is sufficient.  `L` seems to just be a hang over from older versions, again all I can do is refer you to the `man` page.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for your help. Marked as solved.